# Rails server does not start in production - gem related methods are not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

leads to

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `paperclip' for #<Class:0x007fbf49ddafa8> (NameError)
```

This only happens when I start the server in production. In dev and test mode, its all fine.

So I guessed that there is some misconfiguration in the gemfile but paperclip and related gems are not grouped (or excluded for production) so this does not make any sense.

The only gems which are grouped into test/dev only are:

```
group :development, :test do
  # Test driven development
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'faker'

  # check for dead routes
  gem 'traceroute'

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  # find missing translations
  gem 'i18n-tasks', '~> 0.8.3'

  gem 'simplecov'

  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'

  gem 'letter_opener'

  # Model/Controller graphing
  gem 'railroady'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-sidekiq'
end
```

**I'm rather convinced that this has nothing to do with paperclip itself.
If I require paperclip manually in the model, other gem related methods fail as well.**

Here is the full error trace:

```
/Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `paperclip' for #<Class:0x007fbf49ddafa8> (NameError)
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/app/models/sponsorship.rb:2:in `<class:Sponsorship>'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/app/models/sponsorship.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/app/models/advertisement.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /Users/***/Documents/Projekte/***/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace, the class `Sponsorship` has on line 2 a call to a method `paperclip`. This method does not exist in your code or in the `paperclip` gem. You need to look at that line and fix it.

The reason that it is not blowing up in development / test is that the code is not auto-loaded in these environments (specifically, in the configuration `config.eager_load` is set to `true` in production but `false` in development.

If you start a `rails console` in development and run something like `Sponsorship.first` I bet you will see an error.

Comment: Nope. No error. Also on heroku production environment the code works like a charm. Does not make much sense right?